# Чему соответствует это короткое регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Чему соответствует это короткое регулярное выражение?

```
/\[img\]([^[]*)\[\/img\]/ig
```

Интересует именно вот эта часть: **([^[]*)**

Насколько я могу судить, тут составлено следующие:

`[^[]` -  не равно символу `[`Но всё остальное допускается (зачем это нужно, ведь в скобочной группе должна быть url ссылка на изображение, например .

`*` - жадный квантофикатор, равен нулю или более символов (зачем там нуль? Мне кажется там должен стоять `+`)

```
var reg2 = /\[img\]([^[]*)\[\/img\]/ig; 
var match2,text_str;

while (match2 = reg2.exec(text)) {
    console.log(match2);
}
```

Comment: @Doofy, что за бред? В каждом предложении ошибка. 1. Не начало. Он же в символьной группе. 2. Группу запоминают. Но в match2 не она, а массив. 3. Это не тег, а bb-код. Скобки-то квадратные. 4. Содержимое bb-кода - это url картинки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> зачем это нужно, ведь в скобочной группе должна быть url ссылка на изображение

Она и будет. Квадратных скобок в url быть не должно. Ну или их надо заэнкодить.

А какие альтернативы для определения url? Искать отрицание `[/img]`? Ну можно, но зачем?

> зачем там нуль? Мне кажется там должен стоять `+`

Для корректного адреса оба варианта одинаковы. Для некорректного... Ну ok.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я мог бы об этом и догадаться...Эх...Я...

Comment: `А какие альтернативы для определения url? `   Вот - `(.+)`

Comment: @gilo1212, `[img]http://smth/ing1.png[/img] и [img]http://smth/ing2.png[/img]` - с `.+` получится фигня - тогда уж `.+?`. А теперь возьмём битую разметку `Тег [img] позволяет сделать так: [img]http://smth/ing1.png[/img]` - `.+?` сожрёт всё от первого `[img]` до конца - тоже так не делается.

Comment: `.+ получится фигня ` В индексе получается всё нормально, ссылки записываются как нужно. А вот в input записываеся вся строка. Но мы то ищем ссылки, не всё ли равно что записывается в input? Или дольше будет перебираться от того что вся строка записывается каждый раз?

Comment: @gilo1212. Ещё раз. `var s="[img]http://smth/ing1.png[/img] и [img]http://smth/ing2.png[/img]", r=/\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]/ig;` Покажи, каким кодом ты собираешься достать адреса?

Comment: Ты -  Че, мы уже на ты? Ну ладно. Вот смотри -  http://i.imgur.com/ngFaQVJ.png?1

Comment: вот  коТ - `function tested4(text) {
                var reg2 = /\[img\](.+?)\[\/img\]/ig;  
                var match2,text_str;

                while (match2 = reg2.exec(text)) {
                    console.log(match2);
                    
                }       
            }`

Comment: @gilo1212, я со всеми на ты - просто привычка. В последнем коде `.+?`, а не `.+` - о чём мы тогда спорим? Я же как раз сказал, что `.+` не подходит, но `.+?` подходит. А imgur не желает открываться...

Answer (score 3):

Регулярное выражение `/\[img\]([^[]*)\[\/img\]/ig`
соответствует этому `[img]тут что угодно кроме '[' символа[/img]`.

- `i` - Регистронезависимый поиск.
- `g` - Глобальный поиск. Находит все совпадения.

`([^[]*)` - Расшифровывается так:

1. `[^[]` - Найти любой символ кроме `[`.
2. `*` - Соответствует нулю или более `[^[]` выражений.
3. `()` - Захватить всё что попадёт под выражение в скобках.

`*` используется для того чтобы найти вот такой код `[img][/img]`